# Disable NDK platform checking during install

Tags: android, android-ndk

As clearly stated in NDK documentation,

> The new .apk will embed your shared libraries, and they will be extracted automatically at installation time by the system when you install the package on a target device.

Now, suppose I included only a subset of all possible libraries, say only the *armeabi* one. Trying to install on an *x86* device will result in the following error:

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE
```

Is it possible to disable platform checking and proceed anyway, since the application is able to fallback to a pure Java implementation of the native code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My *guess* would be that it is not, however I believe including a nearly/effectively empty library for other platforms of interest would solve your problem at limited effort or package size impact.

I don't know for a fact that you'd actually need a valid .so for an architecture to pass the test, as opposed to a dummy file in the right folder with the right extension (assuming you never try to load it).

But even if you do need a valid one, you could just build the hello-jni sample for all architectures or something like that.  Having a jni function you can call that returns if the library is usable or a stand-in might also be a simple way of solving the detection problem.

Comment: The best ideas are the simple ones! It seems that an empty _.so_ file is enough to install successfully (tested on _x86_ machine, API 18). Other architectures or versions might reject it, but I just needed a quick solution while developing.